# Syntax error using =~ operator in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm very new to bash and I'm trying to extract a portion of a string based on a pattern, but when I execute my code I'm seeing errors.

Sample code:

```
#!/bin/sh

STRING="LAX-8912_Words_Are_Here";

if [[ $STRING =~ LAX-(\d)+ ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

So from the code above, I'm wanting to extract the "LAX-8912" portion of the string. Basically the string will be LAX- and then a series of numbers, could be any length. When the code is exectued however, I'm getting this message:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

I've also tried storing the regex in a variable like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

STRING="LAX-8912_Words_Are_Here";
REX="LAX-(\d)+";

if [[ $STRING =~ $REX ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

But then I get this error:

```
 [[: not found
```

My bash version is 4.2.25 so I'm guessing it's not a version issue, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to what's going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your script starts with:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

it will run the system shell, which may be a completely different shell like `dash`, or at best `bash` in compatibility mode. You should use:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to use bash with all its features.

Similarly, if run with `sh file` you override the shebang and force the script to run with the system shell. Use `./file` so that the script can run with its declared shebang.

Comment: Oh man, how embarrassing, thank you very much for that. My regex appears to be wrong but at least now I can see the output. Thanks again.